# How to Change the Position of a Canvas'es Origin Point

Tags: silverlight, canvas, coordinates

I'm working on a project that allows users to drawing something, and save it in the database.

Basically, the user draws on a canvas, the canvas is 5 time bigger than the screen size, and the canvas is still in the center of the screen (or the screen is in the center of the canvas).

In order to make it flexible for the canvas size (we want to change the size of the canvas in the future), we want to set the center of the canvas as the Origin Point, that is, (0, 0) is in the center of the canvas.  So when the mouse clicks somewhere, the point I get is measured based on the center of the canvas.

Maybe you would say:

1. `Canvas.RenderTransformOrigin = (.5,.5)`. But I'm not asking the rotating center, so it's not the solution.
2. `Canvas.RenderTransform = TranslateTransform (Canvas.Width/2.0, Canvas.Height/2.0)`. But this just move all the objects on the canvas to the center.

You may also say that, why don't we just translate the MouseClick points with an offset `Canvas.Width/2.0, Canvas.Height/2.0`, and then translate them back when rendering.  We could do that, but too much effort, because we have a lot of other operations to be implemented, so every time we have to translate back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have thought of almost every possible approach to this problem, however, I will see if I can add just one more!

The `Canvas` properties, `Left` and `Top`, which dictate an elements position are attached properties. You could create your own attached properties, `OffsetLeft`, `OffsetTop` which allow you to position elements based on the origin you require. These would be simple to implement, when they are get / set, just handle their change event to set the respective `Canvas` attached properties.

Comment: Hi ColinE, Thanks for your reply.  I also thought of a similar approach as your are suggesting, i.e., create another canvas `public PeterCanvas : Canvas`, then add some new properties, such as `OffsetLeft`, `OffsetTop` (as yours). But the coordinates from the mouse click events are still measured based on TopLeft corner (maybe a workaround to this is `e.GetPosition(HelpCanvas)` where `HelpCanvas` is a 0-size canvas which is in the center of the original canvas).  And also, there are a lot of work to do, such as: RenderTransform behavior (the objects on the canvas can this property)...

Comment: @PeterLee I know you are searching for an easy option - but there isn't one I'm afraid!